# User defined function which conditionally splits text into columns Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-functions, oracle12c

I am new to Oracle Databases or Databases in general and I'm coming across a case which is quickly turning into a major headache

I have a query that groups and returns addresses IDs for a given client and each Address ID has an associated type which I need in separate columns

The query I have right now returns something like this:

```
   CLIENT_ID    ADDRESS_AGG_TYP
   12345        6882|HOME;8273|WORK;3192|OTHER
   52345        5523|OTHER;1345|HOME;9547|WORK
   74563        4431|OTHER;6456|WORK;7567|HOME
   34534        1543|WORK;5634|HOME;5123|OTHER
```

ADDRESS_AGG_TYP - is a LISTAGG grouped by client ID on top of a concat of address_id and type from addresses

Table's ddl probably looks somewhat like this.

```
CREATE TABLE addresses
( address_id number(*) primary key,
  client_id number(*),
  type varchar2(70),
  address_line_1 varchar2(70),
  address_line_2 varchar2(70)
);
```

I need to transform the output into something like this:

```
   CLIENT_ID    HOME     WORK     OTHER
   12345        6882     8273     3192
   52345        1345     9547     5523
   74563        7567     6456     4431
   34534        5634     1543     5123
```

Any ideas on how I can make this happen ? I'm guessing this might need a user defined function of sorts but I cannot seem to wrap my head around those.

This is on Oracle DB Version 12 C

Comment: Posting table definitions and sample data is always helpful.  Are `home`, `work`, and `other` the only three possible address types?  And will each client have at most one of each?

Comment: please share the ddl for constructing the two columns CLIENT_ID and ADDRESS_AGG_TYP

Comment: @JustinCave There are 5 possible types with each having only one possible entry per client.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph - added the ddl for the addresses table let me know if that helps.

Comment: You wrote in your question: _Table's ddl probably looks somewhat like this_ Do you know about [Oracle Data Dictionary](http://www.baskent.edu.tr/~tkaracay/etudio/ders/dbase/sql/pdfSQL/DataDictionary.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this using regular expressions and instr.

First i append a ';' to the start of the string, as shown in the data block.

I define the regular expression as a pattern that start with ; followed by numbers and ending in \HOME or \WORK or \OTHER.

Then from the extracted portion i slice it up further to get just the numbers

```
with data
 as (
   select 12345 as client_id,';'||'6882|HOME;8273|WORK;3192|OTHER' as address_agg_typ from dual union all
   select 52345 as client_id,';'||'5523|OTHER;1345|HOME;9547|WORK' as address_agg_typ from dual union all
   select 74563 as client_id,';'||'4431|OTHER;6456|WORK;7567|HOME' as address_agg_typ from dual union all
   select 34534 as client_id,';'||'1543|WORK;5634|HOME;5123|OTHER' as address_agg_typ from dual 
    )
select client_id
      ,substr(
              regexp_substr(address_agg_typ,';[0-9]*\|HOME')
              ,2
              ,instr(regexp_substr(address_agg_typ,';[0-9]*\|HOME'),'HOME')
               -3
              ) as home_extract
      ,substr(
              regexp_substr(address_agg_typ,';[0-9]*\|WORK')
              ,2
              ,instr(regexp_substr(address_agg_typ,';[0-9]*\|WORK'),'WORK')
               -3
              ) as work_extract              
      ,substr(
              regexp_substr(address_agg_typ,';[0-9]*\|OTHER')
              ,2
              ,instr(regexp_substr(address_agg_typ,';[0-9]*\|OTHER'),'OTHER')
               -3
              ) as other_extract                            
  from data


+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| CLIENT_ID | HOME_EXTRACT | WORK_EXTRACT | OTHER_EXTRACT |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
|     12345 |         6882 |         8273 |          3192 |
|     52345 |         1345 |         9547 |          5523 |
|     74563 |         7567 |         6456 |          4431 |
|     34534 |         5634 |         1543 |          5123 |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

db fiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=41a7a4fb3286326b1cb0baf1512aca1b

Comment: This looks great ! Worked perfectly !